# FAILED EXCEPTION Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

Im new to app development and Im working on a tab navigation app, my app was working fine until i tried to remove the Foward action button that comes with the template. I get an instant crash when i try to run my app and after debugging its telling me FATAL Exception at main. Unable to start activity Component Info. If someone could find my error Id be grateful.

Should I be putting the code for my webview in the java class for tab 1 ? i Currently have it in the Main Activity. Ive also added the error when debugging

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "https://www.previewsworld.com/NewReleases?cat=1";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //returning the current tabs
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tab1 tab1 = new tab1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    tab2 tab2 = new tab2();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    tab3 tab3 = new tab3();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return "Weekly";
                case 1:

                    return "Videos";
                case 2:

                    return "Subscribers";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
              app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior=""/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> And ill include my first tab since I was messing with it trying to
>   setup a webview when this all went awry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

   <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error from debugging

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics, PID: 5460
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class webview
              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class webview
              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.webview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics-oGAyzVox825VJ3WIzvxEsw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at com.example.edgar.multiversecorpcomics.tab1.onCreateView(tab1.java:19)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
```

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1613)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:713)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:783)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: Looks like the error is happening in onCreate in tab1.java. Can't tell what the problem is without the code from that.